# SQL error 17002 : Physical DB connection is invalid

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle db(installed in remote machine) from my java application. but, i am getting sql error code 17022. pls let me know how to solve this issue.

Full stack trace

```
MSG: Connecting to jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=dlocdb04)(port=50000))(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=dlocdb04)(port=50000)))(connect_data=(service_name=os02rtdb01svc.world)(server=dedicated))) with Oracle JDBC driver version: 9.2.0.1.0 [cumulative retries=0]
     USER_ID: UNKNOWN

    level: WARN 
     date: 2015-09-21 10:51:45,563
 category: com.retek.merch.utils.ConnectionPool

MSG: [SQL Error code: 17002, State: null] Physical DB connection is invalid. Restarting pool due to the following error.
     USER_ID: UNKNOWN

java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(ERR=1153)(VSNNUM=0)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=1153)(EMFI=4)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dlocdb0401)(PORT=27320))(CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))null))'))(ERROR=(CODE=303)(EMFI=1))))
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:512)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:169)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:149)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:95)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:63)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getNewPoolOrXAConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:547)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:298)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:268)
    at com.retek.merch.utils.ConnectionPool.get(ConnectionPool.java:346)
    at com.retek.merch.utils.TransactionManager.start(TransactionManager.java:59)
    at com.retek.reim.merch.utils.ReIMTransactionManager.start(ReIMTransactionManager.java:49)
    at com.retek.reim.manager.LoginManager.login(LoginManager.java:72)
    at com.retek.reim.ui.login.LoginAction.perform(LoginAction.java:47)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionPerform(ActionServlet.java:1786)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1585)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:509)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:638)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2460)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:157)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
```

Comment: USER_ID: UNKNOWN. Maybe you forgot to specify some login credentials somewhere?

Comment: If you look at the error list it says "Physical DB connection is invalid. Restarting pool due to the following error". This would seem to indicate an error in the setup of the connection pool. You might need to talk to your DBAs about this. Best of luck.

Comment: in java i'm specifying db credentials like this:     
        
        OracleConnectionCacheImpl connMgr = new OracleConnectionCacheImpl();   connMgr.setURL("jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=dlocdb04)(port=50000))(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=dlocdb04)(port=50000)))(connect_data=(service_name=os02rtdb01svc.world)(server=dedicated)))");     
        connMgr.setUser("username");
        connMgr.setPassword("pwd");